# Laravel - delete button

Tags: laravel

Welcome ! I'm new to laravel and i have problem. I start my private project and i want to delete query from database using delete button ( simple todo app). When i click it it doesn't delete but only redirect me to id of this query. Dont know what to do. Can someone help me?

Regards
tomczas

Destroy function in homecontroller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
 $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);
 $todo->delete();
return back();

}
```

home blade

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
          <ul class="todo-list">
            <li>
              <!-- drag handle -->
                  <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
              <!-- checkbox -->
              <input type="checkbox" value="">
              <!-- todo text -->
              <span class="text">{{$todo->tytul}}</span>
              <!-- Emphasis label -->
              <small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{$todo->czas}}</small>
              <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
              <div class="tools">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                {{Form::open([ 'method'  => 'DELETE', 'route' => [ 'home.destroy', $todo ] ])}}
                                {{ Form::hidden('id', $todo->id) }}
                                {{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => ''))}}
                            {{ Form::close() }}
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>
          @endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the form:

```
{{Form::open(['method'  => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['home.destroy', $todo->id]])}}
```

and no need for:

```
{{ Form::hidden('id', $todo->id) }}
```

... laravel does all magick

p.s. make sure You've created resource route to make home controller act as REST controller.

extra, watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pjPXOwKzJM

another way of doing delete function is that - 
You can create some route:

```
Route::get('home/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'HomeController@destroy', 'as' => 'home.delete']);
```

and in this case no need for form:

```
<div class="tools">
  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
  <a href="{{route('home.delete', $todo->id)}}?{{time()}}">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
  </a>        
</div>
```

p.s. after reading Your routes I see also core problem:

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

should be (read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)):

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

Comment: I have this Route::resource('home', 'HomeController@index'); and it still redirects me to http://mypath/1 where 1 is ID task which i want to delete

Comment: @tomczas I've updated my answer. So I'm not depending on "magics" of frameworks and I'm defining my routes exacly, and using "another way of ding" example in my answer.

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home/{$id}/delete', ['use' => 'HomeController@destroy', 'as' => 'home.delete']);
Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogout'));
Route::auth();

Answer (score -1):

Ok second idea is working great but little mistake in spelling:

should be:

```
Route::get('/home/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'HomeController@destroy', 'as' => 'home.delete']);
```

so `{id}` not `:id` and `uses` not `use` Thank u very much for help !

Comment: I've fixed it in my answer (:  I'm not using LV so much last year so forgot how to set the `{id}`  and `:id` is from expressjs (;

Answer (score -1):

in a new version of laravel 5.6 , laravel suggest to use code below to delete one row

`<form method="post" action={{ route('yourControllerDeleteMethodName'), ['yourRowName'=> $yourRowName->slug] }}>
<input type="hidden" value="DELETE"/>
<button type="submit">click to delete</button>
</form>`

this work when you use slug to get row if you use id to get row just write $id instead of slug.

hope to work for you:)\